# estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado para buscar por like pero no encuentra nada

Tags: sql-server-2014

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado para buscar un nombre por like pero al momento de buscar no encuentra ningun resultado
esta seria la consulta

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'BuscarNombreUsuario')
    Begin 
        Print 'El Procedimiento BuscarNombreUsuario >>Ya Existe<<'
    End
ELSE
    Begin 
        DECLARE @BuscarNombreUsuario varchar(900);
        SET @BuscarNombreUsuario = N'Create Procedure BuscarNombreUsuario  
        @NombreUsuario varchar(50) as Select
        IdUsuario,
        NombreUsuario
        From Usuario where NombreUsuario like % + @NombreUsuario + %';
        EXEC(@BuscarNombreUsuario);
        Print 'Procedimiento BuscarNombreUsuario Fue Creada'
    End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un like normal es así:

```
select * from tabla where columna like '%texto%'
```

Concatenando el valor de búsqueda sería así:

```
select * from tabla where columna like '%' + @NombreUsuario + '%'
```

En tu caso sería cada comodín entre comilla doble para armar la cadena junto con el valor de la variable:

```
From Usuario where NombreUsuario like ''%'' + @NombreUsuario + ''%''
```